# Boolean comparaison between a series and a dataframe (element-wise)

Tags: pandas, series

Here the series and dataframe to be compared element-wise (AND condition):

```
import pandas as pd

se = pd.Series(data=[False, True])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[True, False], [True, True]],
                  columns=['A','B'])
```

Desired result:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[False, False], [True, True]],
                  columns=['A','B'])
```

I could achieve that using a slow for loop but I am sure there is a way to vectorise that.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `Series` to numpy array and compare with broadcasting:

```
print (df & se.to_numpy()[:,None])
       A      B
0  False  False
1   True   True
```

Comment: Both valid answer! Can you tell me what the [:,None] part does ?

Comment: @plonfat - It is for [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for convert array `(3,)` to `(3,1)`, it is same like `[:, np.newaxis]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use conversion to `numpy` array to benefit from broadcasting:

```
out = np.logical_and(df, se.to_numpy()[:,None])
```

output:

```
       A      B
0  False  False
1   True   True
```

intermediate:

```
se.to_numpy()[:,None]

array([[False],
       [ True]])
```

Comment: Both valid answer! Can you tell me what the [:,None] part does ?

Comment: This converts the 1D vector (n items) into a 2D array with  1 column and n rows

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df & np.vstack(se))
```

Output:

```
       A      B
0  False  False
1   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.mul(se,0)
```

Output:

```
       A      B
0  False  False
1   True   Tru
```